# Evaluating strings using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `Regex.IsMatch()` to evaluate a list of words.

The `Regex` should return `true` if the following strings are evaluated:
-hellotest
-helloabc
-abchello

and the `Regex` should return false if the following strings are evaluated:
-helloworld
-worldtest
-abcworld

Basically I want it to return `true` if the word `"hello"` is found in the string and if the word `"world"` is ***not*** found in the string.

What's the `Regex` to produce such result?

Comment: Why don't you want to use string.contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the expression

```
(?<!world.*)hello(?!.*world)
```

---

`(?<!prefix)pos` is a negative lookaround. `pos` is only matched, if it is not preceeeded by `prefix`

`pos(?!suffix)` is only matched if it is not succeeded by `suffix`

Comment: @user1295450 - Wow! Why so complicated answer was accepted as the best one? Using variable length negative lookbehind is the worst performance solution. And having two negative lookaround is a devil solution (sorry Olivier!)

Comment: If performance is an issue, why use Regex at all? Abe Miessler's deleted answer `myString.Contains("hello") && !myString.Contains("world");` is probably much faster.

Comment: OP is asking for regex, so we should give him the best regex solution